# RichFaces fileUpload não invoca o listener

Tags: jsf, java-ee, rich-faces

Estou usando a ultima versão do RichFaces, copiei o exemplo do show case no site da RichFaces, e o exemplo não invoca o listener, já tentei de tudo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

xhtml

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
            id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
            maxFilesQuantity="5">
            <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
        </rich:fileUpload>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadBean implements Serializable {
private ArrayList<UploadedImage> files = new ArrayList<UploadedImage>();

public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
    stream.write(getFiles().get((Integer) object).getData());
    stream.close();
}

public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& - LISTENER");
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    UploadedImage file = new UploadedImage();
    //file.setLength(item.getData().length);
    file.setName(item.getName());
    file.setData(item.getData());
    files.add(file);
}

public String clearUploadData() {
    files.clear();
    return null;
}

public int getSize() {
    if (getFiles().size() > 0) {
        return getFiles().size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public long getTimeStamp() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public ArrayList<UploadedImage> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(ArrayList<UploadedImage> files) {
    this.files = files;
}
```

}

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
    <param-value>10000000</param-value>
</context-param>


<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente este outro listener:

```
public void listener(UploadEvent event) {
    this.setUploadItem(event.getUploadItem());
}
```